# Php Laravel uploading .H, .obj, .zip extension file extension files

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-upload

Hello guys I have a situation while uploading file in Laravel I am uploading .H, .obj, .zip extension files so, when size of each of these files is less than 2 mb then only size gets displayed in controller otherwise size gets displayed as 0 so then file becomes not readable.
this is how it looks
"vr_header" => UploadedFile {#30
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Human.h"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 0
    -error: 7
}
"vr_object" => UploadedFile {#31
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Human.obj"
    -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
    -size: 0
    -error: 7
}
I have even tried increasing upload_max_filesize and post_max_size through .htaccess. But, then too getting same response.